# RPC server unavailable calling OpenReadAsync

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, uwp

I have a simple Windows Universal Platform Application that I wrote primarily to teach myself about UWP apps. It works fine, except for what appears to be a somewhat random "The RPC server is unavailable" error generated on the OpenReadAsync method on the StorageFile object.

The application simply builds a list of files to be displayed, then iterates through and displays each one on a timer. Most of the time it works fine. I can let it run for hours no problem. But every once in a while, I receive the RPC error. It seems to happen when I leave the machine for a long time so it logs me out, then I log back in and switch to my slideshow application. It doesn't happen every time, and if I try to reproduce, I can never get it to fail. It seems to be mainly when I leave the machine for a long time - like overnight.

Here is the code running when the error occurs. It happens on the OpenReadAsync method call.

```
StorageFile file = this._files.ElementAt(this._index++);        
await this._dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
{
    var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
    var stream = await file.OpenReadAsync();
    await bitmap.SetSourceAsync(stream);
    this.Image = bitmap;
});
```

If I try to open the file using the Windows Photo viewer, even while sitting at the error, it opens fine. But even re-trying the failing line of code will not allow my app to open the file. All I can do is shut down and restart the application.

Has anyone run across anything like this? Any hints on where I should look?

Thanks.

Edit: Oh, one more thing - the files are all on a local drive. No external servers or network involved.

Comment: Nope. No clues so far. I've just been living with it since it isn't a production app and it doesn't happen very often. Would still like to know what the cause is though.